# Sequence that is Cauchy, bounded, in a complete metric space but does not converge.

Tags: convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I have been stuck on this one for a long time. I need to find a sequence in a complete metric space E such that it is bounded and Cauchy and not convergent. This is kind of tricky. Since E is complete, you just can't have your sequence converge to something outside of E. Since the sequence must be bounded, you can't have a Cauchy sequence that just grows infinitely. I think the sequence must be alternating but I cannot find or come up with any examples of a sequence that is alternating and Cauchy at the same time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, every Cauchy sequence in a complete metric space converges. The sequence you are looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps the question is worded incorrectly or I am mis understood something. I am given d(x_n,x_{n+1}) goes to 0 as n goes to infinity. Is this somehow different than a cauchy sequence?

Comment: To the proposer:  Review the def'n of the Cauchy Criterion.... $\lim_{n\to \infty}d(x_n,x_{n+1})=0$ is  $not$ sufficient for the sequence to be Cauchy.. For example in $\Bbb R$ with $d(x,y)=|x-y|$, if $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+(n+1)^{-1}$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet alright thanks I see now.

Comment: To the proposer: If $d$ is a metric on $X$ and $e(x,y)=\min (1,d(x,y))$ then $e$ is a metric that generates the same topology as $d$  does, and every subset  of $X$ is $e$-bounded. And $e$ is complete iff $d$ is complete. Apply this to the example in my prior comment to get a bounded non-Cauchy sequence  $(x_n)_n$ with $e(x_n,x_{n+1})\to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a Cauchy sequence is automatically bounded.

Secondly, a complete metric space is one where, by definitions, every Cauchy sequence converges, so a sequence you search for does not exist.